# awk to format file using a specific order

Tags: awk

I am trying to format a `tab-delimited` `file` using `awk` and the command runs but no output results.  The `output` is also `tab-delimited`. The format of the output is `$1` `$2` `$2` `$3` `REF=$4`;`OBS=$5` `$6`. Maybe the `awk` is not the best approach as it seems like it should work.  Thank you :).

**file** (~370 lines all in the below format)

```
chr4    70501545    rs28560191  C   A   UGT2A1;UGT2A2
```

**desired output**

```
chr4    70501545    70501545    rs28560191  REF=C;OBS=A UGT2A1;UGT2A2
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2,$2,$3,"REF="$4";""OBS="$5,$6}' file
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here. However, you should `print` the string. Also, why setting the tab in between fields if you have already set OFS?

Comment: I just saw that as well.  I will edit.  Thank you :).

Comment: Note you are now saying `print a, b, c; "OBS=..."`. From the `;`, nothing will be printed. You probably need to `print a, b, c, ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the `print` statement.

```
awk '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" "REF="$4";""OBS="$5 "\t" $6}' file
```

Comment: Thank you all, need coffee :).